# Waiting for a short period of time in EJB 3.0

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I should wait for a short period of time (one or two seconds) in a webservice (EJB 3.0).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834499/waiting-at-most-x-seconds-for-async-ejbs) regarding my problem which seems to be the only legal solution in the EJB world but I still couldn't find a solution how to wait. I was searching a lot but it seem to meg that it cannot be achieved with the tools of EJB 3.0.

Is that true? Or is there a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel `Thread.sleep(2000)` should be a simple solution for the same. Why do you feel that will not work ?

Comment: Hi Deepak, thanks for the reply! The reason why I wouldn't be fond of using Thread.sleep() is that it is absolutely unknown for me what problems can cause in the container if I start managing threads. Probably I am not brave enough to try out :)

Comment: Thread.sleep() sits at heart of JVM. Trust me it will keep things simple. and simple things work seamlessly :) . And here you do NOT have to manage threads; you do not have to use wait() or notify() or yield() which involves deadlock stuff. You have to just add one line of code which is Thread.sleep(2000); and CPU will stop current thread for 2 seconds; do some other work for those 2 seconds; and again come back to that thread after 2 seconds. Period. No further complications.

Comment: Ok, thanks Deepak, You are absolutely right! David confirmed as well that it won't be a big problem to use Thread.sleep() for one or 2 seconds. Thanks again, V.

Comment: Thread.sleep() doesnt even involve creating any other thread which then become tedious to manage.

Answer (score 6):

Waiting 1 or 2 seconds in a thread via `Thread.sleep` is just fine and won't hurt the app server.  There's little difference between this and doing actual work for 1 or 2 seconds.  If we were talking 1 or 2 minutes, that would be of more concern and would merit investigating better options for coordinating communication simply for the fact there are better things to do with your CPU than wait.

The primary motivation for the restrictions in the EJB specification around Threads are really there to prevent people from starting threads or destroying threads (`start()`, `join()`, `stop()`, `suspend()`, etc.) or changing the thread's state (`setName(String)`, `setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader)`, `setDaemon(boolean)`, `setPriority(int)`, etc.).  The key thing to understand is that threads are pooled and reused by the container for efficiency.  So anything that would affect the state of the pool (dirtying a thread by changing the thread object itself) or compete with that pool (starting/stopping threads) is a very big no-no.  The container will also set state in threads indirectly using `ThreadLocal` objects for things such as providing JNDI, Transaction, Security and connection management.  This makes starting/stopping your own threads a doubly big no-no.

Sleeping in a thread is simply a waste of your own servers time and resources.  Not horrible in very small quantities -- it's your time to waste.  Longer times would be of concern.

I would, however, say **never** call `Thread.sleep()` in a **transaction**.  Holding locks and calling `sleep` is a big no-no.  So make sure you mark this method as `@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)` or similar.

Comment: Thanks David, it was a very detailed description! Now I am brave enough to use the Thread.sleep() for 1 or 2 seconds (with the transaction attribute that you mentioned!). Thanks again, V.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait within an EJB method, you could use the famous `Thread.sleep` to pause the current execution thread.

**Beware:** You should not do `Thread` management within EJBs, sleeping is a kind of managment, so pausing an EJB is not considered as a good practice.

It may be, that your requirement is a smell, so it advices you to look at your design, if there is something wrong.

Comment: Thank Burna for the reply! My scenario is that I have got a synchronous webservice and I should retry to call a third-party webservice when I got timeout error. That's why I would need this waiting mechanism in the stateless session bean.

Answer (score 0):

> EJB should not (...) create or manage threads.

Spawning own thread is not preferred in EJB/Application container, especially they are managed by containers.  One approach would be implement using framework/WorKManager to do what ever thread related operation.

> WorkManager is an API from commonj.work(commonj-twm.jar)

Also I believe a stop in EJB is bad by design,rather you could control the delay in your client/service layer by dividing the functionality in to two operations.

Comment: Hi scuba driver,I agree, I don't want to use any thread management but still I need to wait in EJB...

Comment: appreciate if down-vote with a comment :-) , this should help people to answer better

Answer (score 0):

Interaction with thread isn't recommended with EJB, it's the responsibility of the container.

As a work-around, you can try creating a timer with `createTimer(duration, info)`, where you can pass serializable object, if you have to maintain state or hold necessary information for further execution. You can split your logic into two parts/methods, the second method will be executed after specific interval when prior exits.

Therefore, after definied interval, timeout method will be invoked & you can carry the execution forward with the serialized object, if its needed.